# Delete Content of a File in Java

Tags: java, io

I'm writing bytes to temp.fls file. After completing the operation, I want to delete the last 256 bytes from the temp.fls file. How can I achieve this? Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10):

Use [`RandomAccessFile.setLength()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#setLength(long)) like so:

```
RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile(yourFile,"rw");
f.setLength(f.length()-256);
```

Comment: @rekha: spdenne gave you a link to the API documentation. Have a look at it and also at the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;

public class RandomAccessFileDemo {

    public static void main(String ... args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
    {
        File file = new File(<FILE_PATH>);
         System.err.println("MSR:: RandomAccessFileDemo :: the target length is"+file.length());
        RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file,"rwd");
        raf.seek(file.length()-1); // Set the pointer to the end of the file
        System.err.println("MSR:: RandomAccessFileDemo :: the file pointer is"+raf.getFilePointer());

        raf.setLength(raf.length()-raf.length());

    }
}
```

Comment: I hope this would be helpful and tested successfully.

Comment: to remove any number of bytes replace raf.setLength(raf.length()-<number of bytes to be deleted>) as suggested by Stephen.