# How to do IO Write or file delete in J2ME

Tags: java-me

I am making an app for a library

1) The library wants users to install app such that user does not have to access internet after installing app to get list of available books....

2) so what they want is that upon first installation the user will have a set of records distributed along with the jar & if he intends to update the list then he can access the internet

so as per this description i thought of following

1) i will put the list of records inside a text file & store it in /res & distribute the jar

2) upon installing & running the app first time....the data from the text file will be read & store using RMS

3) further any updation can be directly store inside RMS

Now my Q is after running the app first time my text file becomes redundant.....so i want to know

1) how can i delete this text file inside /res programmatically

2) else how can i delete all the contents inside text file....ie how do i do IO write in a text file

Comment: Please, buy some book about Java.

Answer (score 0):

To remove something form .jar you need to first extract the jar then you can remove that file and create jar again.

And the answer for second question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800998/delete-content-of-a-file-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

1. You cannot delete a resource file from your application.
2. You cannot write to a resource file either.

If you feel the file size is too big, then either compress it or download it separately upon first launch of the application.